# Unexpectedly required C++ Template Specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-specialization

I'm trying to implement a generic setter for a container of `Foo` objects.

I do not understand why clang complains about this code given that:

1. you can totally pass a `std::string` or literal to a function that takes `const std::string &` as an argument
2. the template specialization, which does compile and have the expected behavior, has the exact same code as the templated version.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
  protected:
    int _x;
    std::string _name;

  public:
    void set_x(int x) { _x = x; }
    void set_name(const std::string & name) { _name = name; }

    int x() const { return _x; }
    std::string name() const { return _name; }
};

template <typename T, typename Container>
void set_property(Container & container, const T & value, void (Foo::*setter)(T))
{
    for (auto & element : container)
        (element.*setter)(value);
}

// Uncomment this to succeed. 
//
//template <typename Container>
//void set_property(Container & container, const std::string & value, void (Foo::*setter)(const //std::string &))
//{
//    for (auto & element : container)
//        (element.*setter)(value);
//}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 42;
    std::string name = "foo";

    // Initialization.
    std::vector<Foo> foos(10);
    for (auto & foo : foos)
    {
        foo.set_x(x);
        foo.set_name(name);
    }

    x = 17;
    name = "bar";

    // Set properties.
    set_property(foos, x, &Foo::set_x);
    set_property(foos, name, &Foo::set_name);

    std::cout << "x: " << foos[0].x() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "name: " << foos[0].name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

clang error:

```
❯❯  g++ --std=c++20 foo.cpp &&./a.out
foo.cpp:44:5: error: no matching function for call to 'set_property'
    set_property(foos, name, &Foo::set_name);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
foo.cpp:20:6: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') vs. 'const std::string &' (aka 'const basic_string<char> &'))
void set_property(Container & container, const T & value, void (Foo::*setter)(T))
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: The compiler tells you the problem: For the second parameter `T` must be `std::string`, but for the setter `T` must be `const std::string&`.

Comment: Yes... So that's my point. How come it complains? In principle, I should be able to pass a `string` to a function that accepts `const std::string &`, in the exact same fashion that I pass an `int` to a function that accepts a `const int &`

Answer (score 0):

If a template parameter is deduced more than once, it must match exactly throughout the set.

You have:

```
template <typename T, typename Container>
void set_property(Container & container, const T & value, void (Foo::*setter)(T))
```

Note how `T` is used in two separate function parameters, `value` and `setter`.

Now, when you call

```
set_property(foos, name, &Foo::set_name);
```

`T` is deduced twice, from `name` and separately from `set_name`. The two `T`s should be exactly the same. But they are not, `name` says it must be `std::string` while `set_name` says it must be `const std::string&`.

You are saying "oh but it's OK to use `std::string&` where `const std::string&`". This is true, but irrelevant. The two `T`s must be the same. Not almost the same, not compatible in some fashion, but the same.

If you uncomment the overload (it's not a specialization) where `std::string` is hard-coded, you are good to go exactly because now there are no conflicting deductions.

Comment: I see... (Note: you're totally right about the "not a specialization" thing)

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to @n-m-could-be-an-ai, I came up with this solution

Thanks a lot

Cheers

**Updated solution after @Eugene comment**

```
class Foo
{
  protected:
    int _x;
    std::string _name;

  public:
    void set_x(int x) { _x = x; }
    void set_name(const std::string & name) { _name = name; }

    int x() const { return _x; }
    std::string name() const { return _name; }
};

template <typename Container, typename T, typename Setter>
void container_set(Container & container, const T & value, Setter setter, std::type_identity_t<const T> * = nullptr)
{
    for (auto & foo : container)
    {
        (foo.*setter)(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of duplicating the function, you can put its last argument in *non-deduced context*. If you are using C++20, there is a standard thing for it: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity. If not, it is trivial to make your own `type_identity`.

Comment: @Eugene. Correct. Thanks a lot. Although I have to admit that this solution was generated by Copilot and contains a decent amount of what looks like dark magic to me...

Comment: The solution copilot gave you is typical bot garbage – it might "work", but that's not what Eugene was suggesting and wouldn't pass code review

Comment: If you remove the non-nonsensical `, std::type_identity_t<const T> * = nullptr`, then the remaining is yet another solution - having a separate template argument for the type of your member function.